# How to apply condition in boolean field in django rest framework?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

I am working on a blog type website.

where students will ask question and teacher will answer it.

I put two user role
Teacher and student

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    USER_TYPE = (
        ('None', 'None'),
        ('Student', 'Student'),
        ('Teacher', 'Teacher'),
    )
    user_type = models.CharField(choices=USER_TYPE, default='Student', max_length=50)
```

This is the user model where the role is defined.

Post model for submitting the question and Comment model for answering it.

In the Post model I put on field is_answered and as default put it False

```
class add_question(models.Model):
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_answered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

And the answer model [which is comment one] is referred to as the foreign key of the question

```
class submit_answer(models.Model):
    question_id = models.ForeignKey(
        add_question, blank=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Both question and answer model contains created_by field and ForeignKey of User and answer model contains another ForeignKey of question.

so **I need** when the **teacher role** will put a comment the is_answered Field in add_question model should turn as true.
as student also can comment on his/er question so I need on condition to apply.

**I am using serializer as I need API of this**

So, should I modify on my **views.py or serializers.py** and how should I do that!

It would be great help if someone guide me how to do it?

Thanks and let me know if any other information needed.

Comment: Fyi, your class names should be camel-cased. Question and Answer are probably better names.You could override the save() method of the Answer model and update the instance self.question or do the logic in the Answer create view by checking for a 201 created response

Comment: Thanks @wjh18 for your suggestion
lemme try and reach to u
thanks once again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best practice would be adding such codition in `save()` method of `models.Model`. You should name your Model classes differently, like `Question` and `Answer`, because after creating, if you want to edit or something, it would be weird if you have to search for `submit_answer`, right? And as @wjh18 said, use CamelCase in classes.

Also `question_id` is usually bad idea, better think of `question`, because it will lead directly to the whole object, not its id.

```
class Answer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, blank=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.created_by.user_type == 'Teacher' and not self.question.is_answered:
            self.question.is_answered = True
            self.question.save()
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: this should work

Comment: @NixonSparrow Thanks a lot
it's saved me
and thanks I will follow all of yours suggestion
as if class name CamelCase and this question_id as question

thanks a lot